# sum of series using float

Tags: c++, floating-point, series

I calculated the first 20 elements of the series -

[image]

in 2 ways  , 1st  - forward , 2nd - backward. For this I did -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

float sumSeriesForward(int elementCount) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; ++i) {
        sum += (float) 1 / (pow(3, i));
    }
    return sum;
}

float sumSeriesBack(int elementCount) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = (elementCount - 1); i >= 0; --i) {
        sum += (float) 1 / (pow(3, i));
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    cout.precision(30);
    cout << "sum 20 first elements - forward: " << sumSeriesForward(20) << endl;
    cout << "sum 20 first elements - back: " << sumSeriesBack(20) << endl;
}
```

And I got  -

```
sum 20 first elements - forward: 1.5000001192092896
sum 20 first elements - back: 1.5
```

Can someone please explain why is the difference between the 2 ways  ?

Comment: It's more or less basic [What Every Computer Scientist Needs To Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) material.

Comment: When summing a series of numbers using floating point, always sum the smaller numbers first -- Basic floating point 101 -- learned it 40 years ago.

Comment: @HotLicks : you mean it gives better accuracy ?

Comment: @URL87 -- Yes.  When you add a large number and a small number, you lose significance from the small number.  Doing the small numbers first makes them into larger numbers, and hence less loss of significance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, floating point numbers cannot represent values exactly. When you operate on the values errors propagate. In your example, when computing backwards you add small values to ever bigger numbers, having a good chance that the sum of the small numbers so far has an effect on the bigger number. On the other hand, when you compute forward you start with the big numbers and the smaller numbers have ever less effect on it. That is, when summing you always want to sum smallest to biggest.

Just consider keep a sum in just a fixed number of digits. For example, keep 4 digits and sum these numbers top to bottom and bottom to top:

```
values   top to bottom   bottom to top
10.00      10.00            10.01
0.004      10.00            0.010
0.003      10.00            0.006
0.002      10.00            0.003
0.001      10.00            0.001
```

Floating point numbers work just the same way, using a fixed number of [binary] digits.

Comment: Although going bottom to top opens up the possibility of replacing the repeated `pow()` calls to `tmp*=3;`.  It could still work the other way, but you'd have to seed tmp using an initial pow() then divide each time.

Answer (score 5):

To improve accuracy when summing numbers, consider the [Kahan summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). This significantly reduces the error compared to the obvious approach (including summing numbers from smallest to greatest).